# maven can not find package and symbol

Tags: java, maven

I have an app with these class:
(part of class):

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class UserSessionBean implements Serializable {

    @javax.ws.rs.core.Context private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

and during mvn compile, I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project highway-web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/kelevra/java/git/ttkHighway/highway-web/src/main/java/com/kmware/ttk/highway/beans/session/UserSessionBean.java:[28,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] /home/kelevra/java/git/ttkHighway/highway-web/src/main/java/com/kmware/ttk/highway/beans/session/UserSessionBean.java:[40,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] location: class com.kmware.ttk.highway.beans.session.UserSessionBean
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

While making in IDEA there is no such problems. What it could be?

Comment: You have to add the dependency for the HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java file UserSessionBean can not find the class HttpServletRequest.

You should check the dependencies declared in the pom file. Make sure that you include

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Could you try a mvn clean install and see if it produces the same error.

P.S. Are you running the project from console or from an IDE.

Comment: even though this is late...
found this really helpful!
however if you are using annotations in your servlet, you would need to add another dependency: javax.servlet-api

overall, thank you OP